# find number in which range 10 to 20 or 20 to 30 in oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have a table score master contains following fields:

```
    "score_id"   "score_from"   "score_to"       "score_range"        "result"
    1                   10           20           >10 to 20<=          0.04
    2                   20           30           >20  to 30<=         0.05
    3                   30           40           >30  to 40<=         0.06
```

how to tackle in oracle?

1. if pass input number to the table score master 27 then the result should be display as 0.05
2. if i pass input to table 37 then it should give result as 0.06

Comment: What have you tried?  Is this a function you are writing or a `SELECT` with a bind variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution. You just need to put your input value into the bind variable ":x".

```sql
select * 
from Your_Table
where score_from < :x 
    and :x <= score_to
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tried below query -

```
SELECT result
  FROM table
 WHERE num > score_from
   AND num <= score_to
```

You can bind this query inside an oracle function to pass the input number;